# Handling computer mouse pointer with MPU6050 sensor

Tags: mpu6050

I am a student and want to make a project where the computer mouse pointer can be controlled via the MPU6050 sensors. So far I have calculated the below things.

pitch and roll with accelerometer data:

```
def read_word(adr):
    high = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr)
    low = bus.read_byte_data(address, adr+1)
    val = (high << 8) + low
    return val

def read_word_2c(adr):
    val = read_word(adr)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val
accel_xout = read_word_2c(0x3b)
accel_yout = read_word_2c(0x3d)
accel_zout = read_word_2c(0x3f)
accel_xout_scaled = accel_xout / 16384.0
accel_yout_scaled = accel_yout / 16384.0
accel_zout_scaled = accel_zout / 16384.0

Accpitch=round((math.atan2(accel_yout_scaled,accel_zout_scaled)+math.pi) * 180 / math.pi)
Accroll=round((math.atan2(accel_xout_scaled, accel_zout_scaled)+math.pi) * 180 / math.pi)

mouse_coordinates_x=Accpitch*720/360
mouse_coordinates_y=Accroll*480/360
```

My question is: Is this the correct way of mapping the output result(degree of orientation in a 3d plane) to the mouse pointer coordinates(x,y)? Is there any other optimal way to do this? Can anyone please help here or give some hints. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest practical way to achieve this is to get an Arduino based on a 32u4 chip (Leonardo / Esplora / Zero), attach the MPU to it and implement a mouse using the [Mouse functions](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/mouse/).

You can then connect the Arduino the the Pi USB port, and it will be recognized as a mouse.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I have to use raspberry 4 due to some constraints. The final values(x, y) which I am getting is getting mapped with the mouse coordinates. The screen resolution of the pi screen is 720*480 but the values are always somewhere around the (300, 200) range. Therefore it is not working.

Comment: @Frank Then normalize the values you are getting to 0..1 range, and multiply by 720 and 480, respectively.

Comment: I think I found the way but the readings are quite noisy. As my screen resolution is 720*480 and the range of degree is 0-360. I scale up accordingly. I have updated my code above. Note: I did not use the Gyroscope data as it is not giving my correct details. I just mapped Accpitch and Accroll for mapping to mouse coordinates